# Stylus - mixin - variable

Tags: stylus

I think I maybe totally misunderstanding this.

But say I have this repeating css code.

```
.dot_one {
  animation: dot_one 2s infinite linear;
}
.dot_two {
  animation: dot_two 2s infinite linear;
}
.dot_three {
  animation: dot_three 2s infinite linear;
}
```

Shouldn't I be able to extract it as a function like? (but a mixin in stylus)

```
dot_mix(myVar)
    animation: myVar 2s infinite linear;

dot_mix(.dot_one)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the syntax your after

```
dot_mix(sel)
    {sel}
        animation: dot_one 2s infinite linear

dot_mix('.dot_one')
dot_mix('.dot_two')
```

Obtained from here http://www.miniarray.com/use-variables-for-selectors-in-stylus/